# How to manage Book Lending Library in SharePoint?

Tags: library

I need a solution to manage Physical Book Lending Library. Is it possible to do it in SharePoint 2010? If yes, how to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some details, like what exactly you are trying to manage?  Is this a lending library?  and collector's library?  An office library?  Is it merely meant as an inventory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple approach would be to create a list in a site, define the fields you wish to keep track of (title, ISBN, abstract, etc).  Then make sure that all of the people that you wish to be able to use the list have 'Contribute' permissions.

If the library is self-managed then require checkout to modify an item.  Then, the user can merely 'Check out' the book, then 'check in' the book when they return it.  If there is a librarian that will be a gatekeeper then there is no need to check-in/out.  In either case, versioning would also be handy.

That's the super-simple approach.  I can think of a few significantly more usable approaches that would require a fair amount of SharePoint background in order to implement.

Comment: What if you have about 5000 books?  That is too many for a single sharepoint list.  Would an Access web database be better?

Comment: A SharePoint list can hold 50,000,000 items so the quantity is not an issue.  The 5,000 limit comes into play when you attempt to pull back more than 5,000 items or run a query that requires iterating over 5,000 items.  This can be easily solved by proper field indexes and then querying only for that data.

Comment: Really? 50 million?! Then a simple sharepoint list would be all we need for 5000 books? That would be pretty ideal - and searchable. I understand what you mean now by limit.  What do you mean by "proper field indexes"?

Comment: Oops, I misspoke. SharePoint lists can only hold 30,000,000 items - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary.

Comment: An index is merely a field in your sharePoint list that is used often when selecting data.  Good candidates are typically the most exclusive filter used on a common view.  In this case, it could be Year, Artist, ISBN, whatever makes sense in your case.   Here is a Microsoft Video that explains the steps - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/creating-and-using-an-index-RZ101874361.aspx?section=3.  Also, once you create an index, the indexed field must be listed first in your views that use it.  Otherwise, it is not used and you will get the 5,000 item warning on the view.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I, myself did as you suggested and used a sharepoint list with a multiple checkbox column to choose "tags" or "categories".  You have been very helpful.  If I could give you more than one vote, I would.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To develop a book lending library you will need to create a list with a custom Book content type and your site columns like DateOut, DateToReturn, Borrower ...etc.

You will require a user management and registering system.  If your users are in Active Directory meaning company employees it is easy but if this is for general pulbic you can use the ASP.NET way with a SQL database.

Once you have users in DB, you will need them to appear in SharePoint as users.  Then you can associate them with lending entries.

It will be a simple list but you will need a custom web part to view and manage the entries.

So, you need the site columns, content types, lists, web parts and some pages and master page for UI desgn and a user management mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at http://SEBLib.com.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Also, answers should be relevant, and preferably not just a link to a commercial site. Thanks.