# SharePoint 2013 lending library?

Tags: 2013, template

SharePoint 2007 had a library lending template that was used for keeping tracking of books, which were checked out and who to etc.

SharePoint 2013 does not have this template, how can I replicate it? This question ( [How to manage Book Lending Library in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41381/how-to-manage-book-lending-library-in-sharepoint) ) suggests enabling check out/check in on the custom list but this feature only exists for libraries....

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keeping tracks of books is not a SharePoint core functionality..

Comment: How would you suggest implementing this feature?

Comment: What's the problem with the solution suggested in your link?

Comment: The checkin/checkout option cannot be added to custom lists, it can only be added to libraries

Comment: Naturally, since a a custom list has no files attached.

Comment: I know, but the answer from the question above suggests to do this, which is why I can't follow it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9833/discussion-between-robert-lindgren-and-b4z)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this would be either 2 or 3 lists.

- The first one would be the **category**.
- The second one the **book**, tied to the category via lookup.
- The third would be the **person** that it is checked out to, which would
  be tied to the **book** via lookup, and the **category** via lookup.

You could do all of this using Infopath and using filters with secondary data connections on the **book** and **category**.

Then if you are using active directory, use people picker to put the name in on who is checking it out. Have the status as `Checked In` `Checked Out` and "Removed from circulation" (never delete items until your sure it's gone).

Index your category, your status, your books, etc. You can then have a check out date, and the a check in date, and then have a workflow on the chart that would notify the user if the item goes overdue, or is about to become overdue.

The only issue that I see on it is requesting holds. I am unable to give guidance on that one.