# Book lending list in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, workflow

This is my first question on this site.

My task is to make a Book lending list in Sharepoint 2007.
Requirements are:

- I need to store who has the book, from date - till date
- Users can request books, from when they want to have it, and till what date, and there is an approver who approve these requests
- After the request approved, the status will be "borrowed"
- If you borrowed a book, you can request to lengthen the time till you want to have it
- If the book status is borrowed, other users can make a request to borrow it after it has been returned

What would be the best way to make this list?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There a Lending library template available for Sp 2007

> The Lending Library application template helps people manage the
>   physical assets in an organization's library. The application template
>   tracks general properties about the physical assets and which user has
>   currently checked out the asset. It also provides a librarian
>   dashboard to help identify currently available and overdue assets.
>   Automated e-mail notifications can be sent to borrowers who have an
>   overdue item.

Download here [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Application Template: Lending Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19107)

Also have alook on this link:

[How to manage Book Lending Library in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41381/how-to-manage-book-lending-library-in-sharepoint)